# how to find max value with less iterations

Tags: c, interpolation, binary-search, polar-coordinates

I am changing the phase of signal from 0 to 360 by each degree to get max voltage value.Because if i change phase of the signal the voltage also changes.I have the fallowing code to find max value.

```
void Maxphase(float *max, unsigned int *index) 
{
*max = 0.0;
float value;
unsigned int i, data;
for (i=0;i<=360;i++) 
{              
    phaseset(i); 
    delay_ms(100);
    data = readvalue(); 
    value = voltage(mux1);    
    if(value > *max)   //find max value 
    { 
        *max = value;    //max voltage 
        *index = i;   
    }  
}                           
}
```

from the above code I am getting Max value(voltage) after 38 sec(360*100) because for every read operation my device needs 100ms delay. This is too large, I can't change hardware thus i want to get the max value within 2 to 3 sec by optimizing software.
then I have tried with the fallowing code.

```
void Maxphase(float *max1, unsigned int *index1) 
{
  max = 0.0;
  float value;
  unsigned int i,j,data;
  for (i=0;i<=360;i+=10) 
   {              
    phaseset(i); 
    delay_ms(100);
    data = readvalue(); 
    value = voltage(mux1);    
    if(value > max)   //find max value 
    { 
        max = value;    //max voltage 
        index = i;   
    }  
   }    
   *max1=max;
   *index1=index;
   for (i=*index1-9;i<=*index1+9;i+=1) 
     {       
     j=i;       
    phaseset(j); 
    delay_ms(100);
    data = readvalue(); 
    value = voltage(mux1);    
    if(value > *max1)   //find max value 
    { 
        *max1 = value;    //max voltage 
        *index1 = i;   
    }  
    }                         
}
```

I have reduced time from 45 sec to 7 sec. i have reduced iterations 360 to 54(54*100). I want to reduce it 7 sec to 2 sec.

Can any one help me with better algorithm that i can get max value from (0 to 360) with in 2 sec.

I have measured the voltage values using scope by changing phase. I have written below how it vary voltage with phase.

```
Phase (degree)     voltage(max)
  0             0.9mv

 45             9.5mv

 90             9.0mv

135             0.9mv

180             292mv

225             601mv

270             555mv

315             230mv

360             0.9mv
```

I am new to C programming. Can anyone provide sample code for the best algorithm.

Comment: You could start by only measuring at {0,90,180,270), than  interpolate in the quadrant between the top 2 values {180,270} -> 225. etc: binary search.

Comment: What are you doing ? There might be a better way to get the max voltage, needed phase can probably be calculated based on some formula instead of using a simple trial/error.

Comment: @wildplasser I believe your comment is the correct approach, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Is it likely to vary?  I mean you have measured it and printed the values which implies that you think it is stable.  So why do you need to search the whole domain (0..360)?

Comment: By the way, the <= in your for loop is a bug. `(i=0;i<=360;i+=10)`. You should only check 0-360, you are currently checking 0-370.

Comment: Another programming issue might be that you are passing double literals to floats. If your system uses different floating point formats (for example 4-byte float and 8-byte double), then the code might turn ineffective because of this. A float literal is written as `0.0f`, a double literal as `0.0`. So you write for example `float_a = float_b * 3.14`, then you are forcing the calculation to be done in double precision, which is then rounded down to float once more. The compiler may not be able to optimize such code.

Comment: @WilliamMorris  I don't know where is the maximum value, by varying phase from 0 to 360, I will get max value at one point. in my code i am able to find it but it taking more time. I want to reduce the time to catch maximum value.

Comment: Does the signal's shape varies over time?!

Comment: Good! :-) So if the shape does not vary, but only the amplitude, you know in advance where the maximum is located (in degrees) and therfore only need to measure the voltage at this angle +- some degrees. Before measuring it might be necessary to perfom some calibaration in terms of finding the signal start (an offset angle to the angle where to measure).

Answer (score 2):

[Golden section search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search) is probably what you are after.  It is effective, but still pretty simple.

If you want something even faster and more sophisticated, you can use [Brent's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method).

Comment: I don't think these are the right algorithms. [AC voltage](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/phase.html) can be described as a sine wave, so data is of deterministic nature.

Comment: @Lundin: The OP didn't mention AC voltage, and the voltage values don't go negative, but there may be a mathematical relationship that could be taken advantage of.

Comment: Voltage and phase are terms that only occur together in AC voltage supplies.

Comment: Where did you get this from? @Lundin

Comment: @alk Fundamental knowledge about electronic power supplies?

Comment: @Lundin: I plotted the data, and it doesn't look like a sine wave: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ListPlot%5B+%28++0%2C0.9%29%2C+%28+45%2C9.5%29%2C+%28+90%2C9.0%29%2C+%28135%2C0.9%29%2C+%28180%2C292%29%2C+%28225%2C601%29%2C+%28270%2C555%29%2C+%28315%2C230%29%2C+%28360%2C0.9%29%5D+

Comment: OT: I'd more or less agree on it the other way round: In AC power supplies voltage and phase are essentiel parameters ... - but the reverse (as by your statement, mainly the word "*only*") is definitly not true. @Lundin

Comment: @alk Fair enough. Though if you read "phase", "voltage" and 0-360 in the source code, you could make a qualified guess of what the OP is attempting.

Answer (score 1):

If you can be sure that there is only a single highest point on your 360 degrees you can do a recursive divide and conquer.

You start by looking e.g. at 0, 180, 270. Let's say you find the answer is that 180 + 270 together have the highest value. Than you start by looking in at 210.... Which side is higher? And so on ...

Answer (score 0):

Exploiting the various comments and suggestions here, I present this *untested* piece of code. I don't know whether this works at all or is an improvement over the existing source, but it was fun to try, anyway:

```
extern void phaseset(int);
extern void delay_ms(int);
extern float readvalue();
extern float voltage(int);
extern int mux1;

float probe(int phase)
{
    float data;
    phaseset(phase);
    delay_ms(100);
    data = readvalue(); /* data is ignored? */
    return voltage(mux1); /* mux1? */
}

/* helper routine, find the max in a given range [phase1, phase2] */
void maxphase_aux(int phase1, float vol1, int phase2, float vol2, int *phaseret, float *volret)
{
    float xvol1 = 0, xvol2 = 0;
    int xphase1 = -1, xphase2 = -1;

    /* test the voltage in the middle */
    int phasem = abs(phase2 - phase1) / 2;
    float volm = probe(phasem);

    if (volm > vol1 && volm > vol2) {
        /* middle point is the highest so far,
         * search left and right for maximum */
        *volret = volm;
        *phaseret = phasem;

        maxphase_aux(phase1, vol1, phasem, volm, &xphase1, &xvol1);
        maxphase_aux(phase2, vol2, phasem, volm, &xphase2, &xvol2);
    } else if (volm < vol1 && volm > vol2) {
        /* vol1 is the highest so far,
         * search between volm and vol1 for maximum */
        maxphase_aux(phase1, vol1, phasem, volm, &xphase1, &xvol1);
    } else if (volm > vol1 && volm < vol2) {
        /* vol2 is the highest so far,
         * search between volm and vol2 for maximum */
        maxphase_aux(phase2, vol2, phasem, volm, &xphase2, &xvol2);
    } else {
        /* not possible? */
        return;
    }

    if (xvol1 > volm) {
        *volret = xvol1;
        *phaseret = xphase1;
    }

    if (xvol2 > volm) {
        *volret = xvol2;
        *phaseret = xphase2;
    }
}

void maxphase(int *phaseret, float *volret)
{
    float v0 = probe(0);
    float v360 = probe(360);
    maxphase_aux(0, v0, 360, v360, phaseret, volret);
}
```

Comment: I have tried to understand but i am confusing about function "void maxphase_aux(int phase1, float vol1, int phase2, float vol2, int *phaseret, float *volret)". Can you give some little bit description about how this code works.

Comment: @user1759248 I added some comments to clarify the working. As I already said, I don't know whether this works. There are likely some bugs in it.

Comment: Thanks for your code. I will try to understand and i will test it.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: 2012-11-10.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define FAKE_TARGET 89
unsigned fake_target = FAKE_TARGET;

float probe_one(unsigned int phase);
void Maxphase(float *max, unsigned int *index);

void Maxphase(float *max, unsigned int *index)
{

unsigned int aim, idx, victim;

struct best {
    unsigned pos;
    float val;
    } samples[4] = {{0, 0.0}, };

    for (aim = 0;aim < 360;aim += 90) {
        idx=aim/90;
        samples[idx].pos = aim;
        samples[idx].val = probe_one(samples[idx].pos);
        if (!idx || samples[idx].val < samples[victim].val ) victim = idx;
        }

        /* eliminate the weakist postion, and rotate the rest,
        ** such that:
        ** samples[0] := lower boundary.
        ** samples[1] := our best guess
        ** samples[2] := upper boundary
        ** samples[3] := scratch/probe element
        */
    fprintf(stderr, "Victim=%u\n", victim );
    switch(victim) {
    case 0: samples[0] = samples[1]; samples[1] = samples[2]; samples[2] = samples[3]; break;
    case 1: samples[1] = samples[3]; samples[3] = samples[0]; samples[0] = samples[2]; samples[2] = samples[3]; break;
    case 2: samples[2] = samples[1]; samples[1] = samples[0]; samples[0] = samples[3]; break;
    case 3: break;
    }


        /* Calculation is easier if the positions are increasing.
        ** (We can always perform the modulo 360 if needed)
        */
    if (samples[0].pos > samples[1].pos ) samples[1].pos  += 360;
    if (samples[1].pos > samples[2].pos ) samples[2].pos  += 360;

    while( 1) {
        int step;

        step = samples[2].pos - samples[0].pos;
        if (step < 3) break;

        do    {
            fprintf(stderr, "\n[%u %u %u] Diff=%d\n"
            , samples[0].pos , samples[1].pos , samples[2].pos , step);
            if (step > 0) step++; else step--;
            step /= 2;
            aim = (samples[0].pos + step ) ;
                /* avoid hitting the middle cell twice */
            if (aim %360 != samples[1].pos %360) break;
            step += 1;
            aim = (samples[0].pos + step ) ;
            if (aim %360 != samples[1].pos %360) break;
            step -= 2;
            aim = (samples[0].pos + step ) ;
            break;
            } while(0);

        fprintf(stderr, "Step=%d Aim=%u, Idx=%u\n",step, aim,idx );

        samples[3].pos = aim;
        samples[3].val = probe_one( samples[3].pos );

        victim= (samples[3].pos > samples[1].pos ) ? 2 : 0;
        if (samples[3].val > samples[1].val) idx= 1; else idx = victim;

        fprintf(stderr, "Victim=%u, TargetIdx=%u\n", victim, idx );
                /* This should not happen */
        if (samples[3].val < samples[victim].val) break;
        if (idx != victim) samples[2-victim] = samples[idx];
        samples[idx] = samples[3];
        }

    *max = samples[1].val;
    *index = samples[1].pos % 360;
}
float probe_one(unsigned int phase)
{
    float value;

#ifdef FAKE_TARGET
    int dif;
        dif = fake_target-phase;
    if (dif < -180) dif = 360+dif;
    else if (dif > 180) dif = 360-dif;
        /* value = 1.0 / (1 + pow(phase-231, 2)); */
        value = 1.0 / (1 + pow(dif, 2));
        fprintf(stderr, "Target = %d: Probe(%d:%d) := %f\n", fake_target, phase, dif, value );
        sleep (1);
#else
    unsigned int data;
    phase %= 360;
    phaseset(phase);
    delay_ms(100);
    data = readvalue();  // what is this ?
    value = voltage(mux1);
#endif

return value;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
float value;
unsigned int index;

if (argv[1]) sscanf (argv[1], "%u", &fake_target);
fake_target %= 360;

Maxphase(&value, &index) ;
printf("Phase=%u Max=%f\n", index, value );
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am confusing about your code can you give me some more explanation, which method is used. When i run your code in CodeVision AVR i am getting error like "undefined symbol fprintf". If i remove fprintf then i am getting warning like "local variable "frist" is used before its set.

Comment: It is just plain ordinary binairy search. If your platform does not have stdout: that is your problem. BTW: the code is not right yet: it fails if the two best points are positions at different sides of the 0/360/northpole. I am working on it. BTW: do you have enough memory on your target machine ?

Comment: How much memory, I think i have enough memory. what does it mean "it fails if the two best points are positions at different sides of the 0/360/northpole"

Comment: The new version uses a float array of 360 cells. (not strictly needed, but convenient. It would cost 360*sizeof(float) bytes, probably on the stack. (instead of the 3*8 in the current version, which is minimal). BRB in about three hours.

Comment: I haven't seen any changes in the code,You said i am going to update with in three hours.

Comment: @user1759248: it took me more than a few hours. It seems to work now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your code. It took some time for me to understand. I am sick so i am out of internet. I am working on it now.I have small problem. Once i got maximum phase then I have to subtract 4.32(degrees) from that maximum phase. I have tried to store maximum phase value (unsigned int) into some float variable and i have subtracted 4.32 from that float variable but it is printing like -32456 or 6456. what will be the problem?

Comment: Well, I run the code a few times, and it is still not perfect (there are some uncovered corner cases, so it seems). NB: you do use a "%f" format for printing the float value? Maybe make that into a new question?